# Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{1-D}$, where $D$ is the differential operator

Tags: operator-theory, taylor-expansion, differential-operators

I understand that we can represent $e^D$ simply as a power series of D. But what about functions of D which are not entire on the complex plane? What if the function has no taylor expansion, or if it is only valid in a certain region.

An interesting example to me is $\frac{1}{1-D}$. The taylor expansion for this function is valid for $|D|<1$ which makes no sense.

If I were to try applying the taylor expansion of this function and then apply $(1-D)$ on the result, I would indeed get the original function, indicating that the power series was valid, which leads me to believe that $|D|$ is indeed less than 1.

What is the meaning of this all, what am I misinterpreting?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're saying. What do you mean by "apply $(1+D)$" on the result. Do you mean you want to evaluate $f(D)=1/(1-D)$ via $f(D+1)$? Anyways, the theory of taylor/laurant expansions in complex analysis guarantees that the expansion of any analytic function $f(D)$ around $D_0$ is valid up to the radius of the first singularity. So for example if $f(D)=1/(1-D)$ then $D=1$ is such a singularity and $F(D)=1+D+D^2+\cdots$ is valid for $|D|<1$. Beyond this the expansion is not valid, and one needs to analytically extend it, in this case by declaring $F(D)=1/(1-D)$ for $D>1$.

Comment: @AlexR. : What in the world could $|D|<1$ or $|D|>1$ possibly mean when $D$ is supposed to be $\dfrac d{dx}$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Its spectral radius?

Comment: @AlexR. What is that? It is actually related?

Answer (score 2):

One has to specify a space of functions (or some linear space, if you are not interpreting the elements as functions) on which $D$ acts, and some topology with respect to which $\sum D^n f$ might converge, or not converge, to an element of the space.  For example, the series $(1-D)^{-1}$, interpreted as a power series, does always converge and give a meaningful result when applied to the vector space of polynomials in one variable.

Your calculation shows that, if the sum does converge in some specified sense, applying $(1-D)$ to it does recover $f$.

Comment: Consider the example $$F(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{d^n }{dx^n}\sin(ax)$$ For $|a|<1$, I can numerically calculate (which I can't do for |a|>1) and then numerically find that $F(x)-F'(x)=\sin(ax)$

Comment: It is an example of the final sentence in the answer: when it converges (|a| < 1) then (1-D) applied to the result recovers the function.  When it doesn't converge, there is still a solution to the ODE  g - g' = f  but it is described by an integral and not a power series in D.

Comment: Which is similar to the fact that when $|x| > 1$, there is a solution to the algebraic equation $(1-x) y = 1$ but it is no longer given by the usual geometric series.  There is a series in negative powers of $x$ for that case, and the translation of that fact into the differential operator setting is that there will be a solution of the ODE using repeated integration instead of repeated differentiation. It's just that nobody would use it when the whole thing can be solved exactly with a single integration.